# save array 3D in CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, opencv

Sorry I have a problem to save the data in a csv, what I want to save is a 3d array of images, I could save it, the problem arises when reading the csv, since it is saved as a string, so I can not read the data to create the image, try to use the astype ("uint8"), since that is the format I need someone helps me how to save the data with the format I need or change the format when recovering the data.

```
    new_dt=pd.read_csv('mypic2.csv')

    for x in range(len(a.index)):
        imagess=a.img[x]
        print(imagess)
        cv2.imshow('imagenew', imagess)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from the question why you would want to use pandas dataframes to store the image. I think this makes things unnecessarily complicated. You may instead directly store the numpy array in binary format and load it again at some point later.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#create an image
imar = np.array([[[1.,0.,1.],[0.,0.,1.],[1.,1.,0.]],
                 [[0.,1.,1.],[0.,1.,1.],[1.,2.,3.]],
                 [[0.,0.,1.],[1.,1.,1.],[1.,0.,0.]]]).transpose()
plt.imsave('pic.png', imar)

#create dataframe

df = pd.DataFrame([[0,""]], columns=["Feature1","Feature2"])

# read the image
im = plt.imread('pic.png')

plt.imshow(im)
plt.show()

#save the image array to binary file
np.save('mypic.npy', im)
# store name of image in dataframe
df.iloc[0,1] = 'mypic.npy'
#save dataframe
df.to_csv("mydf.csv")
del df

#read dataframe from csv
df = pd.read_csv("mydf.csv")
# load the image from binary file, given the path from the Dataframe
new_im= np.load(df["Feature2"][0])
# show the loaded image
plt.imshow(new_im)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I put it in a csv why I keep thousands of images, because it is from a game then that game is generated an array of RGB in 3D, and how I am new using this then I happened to save the arrayanes in csv

Answer (score 1):

I am also not so sure why you would want to save an image as csv. Since you are working with `opencv`, why don't you use `cv2.imwrite`, which is compatible with your `cv2.imshow`.

Another way to save an `opencv` image is using `numpy.save` since an `opencv` image is essentially an `np.array`.

If you must save it in `csv`, then you could create a data frame like

```
          width . height .  0  .  1  . ...
image_1 .   w1  .   h1   .  f0 .  f1 . ...
image_2 .   w2  .   h2   .  f0 .  f1 . ...
```

where each row contains the image's width and height followed by `image.flatten()`. Then you could modify your script as

```
new_dt=pd.read_csv('mypic2.csv')

for x in range(len(dt.index)):
    # recover image's dimension
    width = new_dt.iloc[x,0]
    height = new_dt.iloc[x,1]

    # load image and reshape to original dimension
    images = new_dt.iloc[x,2:].reshape(height, width, -1)
    print(imagess)
    cv2.imshow('imagenew', imagess)
```